# Always passing -A (--askpass) to sudo

Tags: sudo, gnupg, password-store

I would like sudo to always do as if I had passed the -A (--askpass) option.

I would like that so that sudo always uses my gnupg agent and password store. It already works if I pass -A manually, but I would like -A to always be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would an alias be enough? You can go to your $HOME/.bashrc file and bellow other existing alias you can enter

```
alias sudo='sudo -A'
```

I have similar customized alias in my .bashrc file that work fine.

Before to make it permanent, you can try it in your shell to verify that works ok.

Comment: I thought about that right after I laid down in bed :-). Thanks anyway for your answer.