# Always use sudo askpass except when called from an interactive shell

Tags: sudo

I have seen [the existing question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326430/always-passing-a-askpass-to-sudo) about this, but the answer only specifies using an alias, which would mess up the interactive shell and not work for applications using exec() or similar means. I don't really want to move the sudo executable in /usr/bin because it would make upgrading difficult, but I don't really know how else this would be done. I would also like it to use askpass when called from a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the [current bash instance is interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html). However this may not work for other shells.

Now if you create a proxy script you can encapsulate the decision how to start `sudo`. Name it `sudoAskpass.sh`, for instance:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

BASH_PARAMETERS="$1"
shift

case "${BASH_PARAMETERS}" in
    *i*)
        sudo -A "$@"
        ;;
    *)
        sudo "$@"
        ;;
esac

exit $?
```

You need to alias `sudo` nevertheless, as within the script the `$-` parameter indicates a non-interactive shell:

```bsh
alias sudo='/path/to/sudoAskpass.sh "$-"'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood; I want the askpass to always be active, but I don't want to have to edit every script to use sudoAskpass.sh because aliases don't carry over to scripts

Comment: @goose121 Well, your question missed the point to explicitely state what your real problem was, so I made some assumptions. Glad I could help, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. First, make a script called `sudo` somewhere which is before `/usr/bin` in your path with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/sudo -A "$@"
```

This just passes its arguments onto the real sudo, but appends the -A argument. Then, in `/etc/zshrc` (or your shell's system-wide rc-file), make an alias back to the original sudo:

```
alias sudo="/usr/bin/sudo"
```

Comment: Note: This solution depends on the order of directories in `PATH`. It won't work if `/usr/bin` is placed before `/usr/local/bin`,

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add that.